# What is the tattoo on Monkey D Dragon's face?

Tags: one-piece

I would like to know if Oda has offered any explanation as to what the tattoo on his face signifies/denotes, or if something has been said about it in the anime/manga.

[image: Monkey D Dragon]

Comment: I really doubt that holds any significance. It could just be the style that Oda Sensei has given to him. Other that than, nothing has been revealed about him as of now!

Comment: Has noone asked Oda in a SBS? Also, I think there must be some backstory to that tattoo. It doesn't make sense for him to have such a design on his face for looking stylish.

Comment: Even if there is any story behind that tattoo. I dont think it has been revealed yet. We just need to wait for him to write an arc related to the revolutionaries and their lives.

Comment: AFAIK Oda-sensei hasn't revealed whether or not the tattoo has any meaning. He didn't even reveal much of Dragon so far.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Oda sensei has said nothing about it. The tattoo wasn't present in Volume 0 when Roger was executed 24 yrs ago, but present 12 yrs ago when Dragon saved Sabo. So it is clear that Dragon had it after the Age of Exploration. Theories exist as to what it means, judging from this fact.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its because at one stage in his life for the bloodline of garp dragon and luffy is that at one stage of their life they get a mark on their face that represents that they are at the most powerful point at their life but when their power decreases because of old age, it slowly fades away.